# What are the differences among these phrases? as long as VS so long as VS as far as VS so far as

Tags: word-difference

It is hard to tell the differences these phrases below.

Are they really different or interchangeable?

1. as long as
2. so long as
3. as far as
4. so far as

Answer (score 1):

**As far as**

1. To show distance

> I'll go *as far as* Madrid.

2. To show "concern"

> He was happy *as far as* the cost of the yacht was concerned.(He was happy regarding the cost of the yacht)
>
> He can leave *as far as* I am concerned.

3. To show limit of knowledge

> There is no monster under your bed *as far as* I know.

**So far as**

This is slightly less formal version of *(in) so far as*. This can be used instead of **as far as.**

**As long as**

1. To show time

> I'll wait for you *as long as* the kingdom comes.

2. To show a requirement

> I'll come to the party *as long as* there is no dancing. (I'll come to the party given there is no dancing)

**So long as**

This can be used instead of **as long as** in less formal situations.

Comment: what does " concerned " mean in the sentence "  He was happy as far as the cost of the yatch was concerned " ?

Comment: Note that the correct phrase is "insofar as," not "in so far as."

Comment: Actually, my apologies. It depends on where you are: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8023/insofar-or-in-so-far